# How can I extract all img tag within an anchor tag?

Tags: php, domdocument

I would like to extract all img tags that are within an anchor tag using the PHP DOM object.

I am trying it with the code below but its getting all anchor tag and making it's text empty due the inside of an img tag.

```
function get_links($url) {

    // Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    // Load the url's contents into the DOM
    @$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

    // Empty array to hold all links to return
    $links = array();

    //Loop through each <a> tag in the dom and add it to the link array
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) 
    {
       $hrefval = '';
       if(strpos($link->getAttribute('href'),'www') > 0)
       {
           //$links[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'), 'text' => $link->nodeValue);
           $hrefval = '#URL#'.$link->getAttribute('href').'#TEXT#'.$link->nodeValue;
           $links[$hrefval] = $hrefval;
       }
       else
       {
           //$links[] = array('url' => GetMainBaseFromURL($url).$link->getAttribute('href'), 'text' => $link->nodeValue);
           $hrefval = '#URL#'.GetMainBaseFromURL($url).$link->getAttribute('href').'#TEXT#'.$link->nodeValue;
           $links[$hrefval] = $hrefval;
       }
    }

    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('img') as $link) 
    {
        $srcval = '';
       if(strpos($link->getAttribute('src'),'www') > 0)
       {
           //$links[] = array('src' => $link->getAttribute('src'), 'nodval' => $link->nodeValue);
           $srcval = '#SRC#'.$link->getAttribute('src').'#NODEVAL#'.$link->nodeValue;
           $links[$srcval] = $srcval;
       }
       else
       {
           //$links[] = array('src' => GetMainBaseFromURL($url).$link->getAttribute('src'), 'nodval' => $link->nodeValue);    
           $srcval = '#SRC#'.GetMainBaseFromURL($url).$link->getAttribute('src').'#NODEVAL#'.$link->nodeValue;
           $links[$srcval] = $srcval;

       }
    }

    //Return the links
    //$links = unsetblankvalue($links);
    return $links;
}
```

This returns all anchor tag and all img tag separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[contains(@href, "www")]/img') as $entry) {
    var_dump($entry->getAttribute('src'));
}
```

Comment: Not to be a nitpicker, but you missed a closing paranthesis. `var_dump($entry->getAttribute('src'));` :)

Comment: But in this code, how can i check a particular anchor has a particular img tag ?

Comment: The XPath used - "//a/img" will get all <img> nodes which are children of <a> nodes

Comment: But i am having many <a> tags single and having child node as img in a document . Then how can i identify that which <a> tag has which img tag ?

Comment: @J.J. If loop over the result, you'll have only those anchors, that have an image inside and you get those anchors as DOMNodes, so you can add an ID or a class to identify them further. (Did you even tried the above?)

Answer (score 0):

The usage of strpos() function is not correct in the code.

Instead of using

```
if(strpos($link->getAttribute('href'),'www') > 0)
```

Use

```
 if(strpos($link->getAttribute('href'),'www')!==false )
```